# Permanent URL of ActiveStorage objects in S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I have a model called `Campaign` and every `Campaign` has one attachment.

I use S3 ActiveStorage storage and I need a PERMANENT URL for my `Campaign` images.

I currently generate URLs like:

```ruby
campaign.image.service_url
```

But this link expires in 5 minutes. I need non-expire links. (Config settings only let me get a URL that expires in 1 week, it does not solve my problem again)

How can I get URLs of my images?

EDIT

Solution:

I use CloudFront as CDN. This is the solution I found:

https://domainName+/campaign.image.key

this gives a link to an image file that does not expire.

Answer (score 2):

Check the docs https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Variant.html#method-i-service_url

You are not supposed to expose `service_url` directly:

> Returns the URL of the variant on the service. This URL is intended to be short-lived for security and not used directly with users. Instead, the service_url should only be exposed as a redirect from a stable, possibly authenticated URL. Hiding the service_url behind a redirect also gives you the power to change services without updating all URLs. And it allows permanent URLs that redirect to the service_url to be cached in the view.
>
> Use url_for(variant) (or the implied form, like +link_to variant+ or +redirect_to variant+) to get the stable URL for a variant that points to the ActiveStorage::RepresentationsController, which in turn will use this service_call method for its redirection.

So use `url_for(campaign.image)` (or `url_for(campaign.image.some_variant)`) instead.

Comment: I got error message like undefined method `url_for' . How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

With active storage you can do

```
url ="#{campaign.image.service.bucket.url}/#{campaign.image.blob.key}"
```

Then you would need to configure the public access settings on the S3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

The URL that is not expire is simple and without any params:

```
http[s]://[bucket-name.s3].amazonaws.com/pathtofile/file.extention
```

You can get this URL from the AWS SDK by using S3::Objects `:public_url` method

Comment: How can I get path to file?

Comment: I can't apply it to my situation :(

I call campaign.image in another model. So I need this URL in different model a custom method. How can I use public_url?